# Payment from PayPal in purchase order in Odoo 12

Tags: paypal, odoo, payment, odoo-12, purchase-order

I have a condition where I have to make payment through PayPal from purchase order. By default, PayPal payment is only available for sale quotation now. Is this possible to make payment through PayPal from purchase order?

Comment: you want to pay for your own purchase orders in your Odoo system?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @arryph yes my own purchase order.

Comment: ok @halfer, i'll take care.